# how to get a file that contain a particular string in file name

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

i am trying to get a file that contain a particular string in filename.
for example there are several files in directory ,i want the files who is having the "index" or "export" in filename.Any piece of code or approach will help

Comment: You need to try first after that you can ask for some help you can't just ask here people to make what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like below using `os module`. Inside `os.walk`, you can use desired path, i am using current directory.

```
import os

for path, b, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    print('The path is ', path)
    for file in files:
        if 'index' in file or 'export' in file:
            print(file)
```